# How do I count the number of different child id's belonging to a parent record?

Tags: mysql

For instance I have two tables in a music database.

Table album and table track.

Each track record has (amongst other things), an album_id and an artist_id

Each album record has a unique album_id

In order to spot which albums are by 'various artists' I want to count the number of distinct artist_id's which belong to each album.

Such that two or more track records with the same album_id but with differing artist_id's should signal that I can flag the album as 'various artists'

I can do it with multiple queries but I'm seeking the elegant all in one query.

Comment: So, you want a result with all the `album_id` that have more than 1 artist? All just count how many (such albums) exist?

Comment: And what is your DBMS? SQL-Server, MySQL, Oracle, Postgres, ...?

Comment: A result with all the album_id's

Comment: Sorry, forget to answer DBMS question it's MySQL

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to solve this problem, but with a composite index on `(album_id, artist_id)` most DBMS will manage to use only this index (a full index scan) with the following query and thus be quite efficient:

```
SELECT album_id
FROM track
GROUP BY album_id
HAVING MIN(artist_id) < MAX(artist_id) ;
```

If you also want the number of artists per album, you can add `COUNT(DISTINCT artist_id)` in the select list.

---

A less obfuscated alternative condition is to use (which could be less efficient than the above `MIN < MAX` method):

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT artist_id) > 1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help.
This did the trick.
I'd be interested to see other solutions out of curiosity.